PHP: Date: Show german weekday name
i have my function, but i don't find a solution which works wo show the date in german.
function getDatetime($match)
{ 
    $datetime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
    $datetime = new DateTime($match["matchDateTime"]);
    $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter( 
    "de-DE", 
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG, 
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
    "Europe/Berlin", 
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 
    "EEEE', ' H:i Uhr" 
); 
    return $formatter->format($datetime);
}

But it's Freitag, 20:
The Date is cutted. Whats wrong?
Thanks!

Use classes IntlCalendar and IntlDateFormatter. They support locales, timezones and other nice things like the definition of the first-week-of-year and first-day-of-week.

I used it, but now my date is incomplete :-O

You should use
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
to indicate your script that you want the time for Germany and for testing you code you can use below code after that:
echo date("l"); //lower case "L",
Or there is another way,If you want it to return the output in German,You should check that (intl) extension is enabled in your PHP installation.then you can enter the following code :
$today = date("H:i:s");
$date = new DateTime($today);
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE' , IntlDateFormatter::Full, 
IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
echo $formatter->format($date);

